# Converting Initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I need to convert a class written in C++ 0x to one which compiles in Visual studio 2008. 
The code uses std::initializer_list.

Following is the  code

```
template <typename data_type>
class symmatrix
{
public:


    typedef data_type         value_type;
    symmatrix(std::initializer_list<T> const& size, value_type ini = value_type())
      : m_data(0), m_memory(false) { resize(size); *this = ini; }
}
```

has to be converted to old standard understood by VS 2008.

I am really struggling to change 100 lines of  new C++ code to old C++. So, please help me.

Comment: Do you understand that changing the constructor means in all likelihood changing all sites that use that constructor? It's possible to write a constructor that is *equivalent* semantically but it will not be source-compatible with the old one.

Comment: If you are currently (judging from your questions) on producing a VS2008 compatible version of a C++0x (VS2010?) project, I recommend that you take your time to read the documents that lead to the modifications of the standard and what the equivalences in code represent. Depending on how much current code uses that class, and whether you want to maintain the two versions (C++03/0x) you might decide that some features of the class are not worth it and drop them from the C++03 version.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of an `initializer_list` you can choose to pass a pair of iterators. But you'll have to change client code as well.

If it is a well-written class, it's bound to have other constructors, such as the one I mentioned. In this case I'd recommend to just remove the overload that takes an `initializer_list`. Client code may have to be changed as well, if it uses that constructor.

Comment: Sorry I could not get it. 
Could you suggest with some example.